# UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter

Tags: view, hive, hql, explode

I am trying to run some hive queries related to create view.The command to create l1 is working fine but after running the command to create view l2 it shows error.

`create view l1 as select id, words from tweets55 lateral view explode(sentences(lower(text))) dummy as words;`

`create view l2 as select id, word from l1 lateral view explode( words ) dummy as word ;`

The error is 
`FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter`

I have added the jar hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar